# What is the functionality of read-timeout attribute?

Tags: java, jboss, timeout, wildfly-9

I want to understand the functionality of `read-timeout` in a web application running on JBoss / WildFly server.

Following are the changes carried out in standalone.xml file:

`<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" read-timeout="20000"/>`

Also, what is the default value of the attribute if it is not mentioned explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/10.0/subsystem/undertow/server/http-listener/index.html)

> Configure a read timeout for a socket, in milliseconds. If the given
>   amount of time elapses without a successful read taking place, the
>   socket's next read will throw a {@link ReadTimeoutException}.

It also says that it is Nillable so I don't know if null, how wildfly behaves.